# What determines Last Opened timestamp on a file

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem

I have files in Finder sorted by Last Opened. Most files seem to be sorted by when they were opened, but not all of them, and some being years behind. Why?

For example...

- If I open an image with Preview, it is considered opened.
- If I open a text file with a text editor, it is considered opened.
- If I use Quick View on any file, it is *not* considered opened
- If I play an mp3 in iTunes it is *not* considered opened.
- If I edit an mp3's id3 tag in iTunes it is still *not* considered opened.

Comment: Further evidence that iTunes is just plain evil.....